# Checking to see if an array has any strings in an array list

Tags: java, arrays

```
ArrayList<String>  mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
build2 = "";
  String[] source = file2.split(" ");
  for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++){
    int offset = mylist.indexOf(source[i]);

    if(Arrays.asList(source).equals(mylist)){
    build2 += (char)(65 + offset);
    }

  }

  System.out.println("\nYour decrypted message is: \n" + build2);
```

This is a encryption and decryption project.  Right now the string array mylist contains a bunch of unicodes for poker cards.  And my array source contains poker cards and number.

I would like to check, if there are poker cards in the array then display-

> build2 += (char)(65 + offset); (which converts certain poker cards to letters)

My full code is here - 
https://repl.it/@MatthewZeman/DecryptionCode
https://repl.it/@MatthewZeman/EncryptionCode

> input -

```
 36  36
```

> output -

```
ABC
```

Comment: What you wrote is very confusing, I read it three times and didn't get what you want... Can you at least provide an example of input and your desired output ?

Comment: @SchiduLuca does that help? It is a little bit hard for me to explain

Comment: What is your current output? Describe problems that you ran into.

Comment: My current output doesn't display anything @CrazySabbath.  Right now I want it to only display a letter if there are poker cards in the array that are also in the arraylist

Comment: @IGotManyQuestions seems that `if(Arrays.asList(source).equals(mylist)){` will never equal true, that is why you don't get any output as `build2` will never be mutated

Comment: @Lino thats the problem im running into, I need the if statement to check if the array contains the same strings as the arraylist

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [List.containsAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)).

[List.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) only returns true if both Lists contain the same elements in the **same order**.

If you want to check that all elements are present in both lists:

```
if(Arrays.asList(source).containsAll(mylist)){
   build2 += (char)(65 + offset);
}
```

Comment: Im sorry I have never worked with .containsAll before, do you mind showing me how to apply it to my code specifically?

Comment: I added an example but I think there is more stuff you have to improve in your code to make it work.